# Drawing a circle at my mouse location when I hit the space bar (Pygame)

Tags: python, pygame, draw

I am attempting to draw circle at the location of my mouse whenever I hit the space bar. The goal is to draw this circle around a character that is following my mouse cursor and kill other objects it comes in contact with. Am I on the right track, also how the heck does drawing a circle work

```
import math
import pygame, sys, time 
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
WINDOW_WIDTH = 1000
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption('follow mouse')
surface.fill((255,255,255))

class Hero():
    def Attack(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            surface.fill ((255,255,255))
            amntTuple = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            pygame.draw.circle(surface, BLUE, amntTuple, 20, 300)
            surface.blit (self.space, self.spaceRect)
            pygame.display.update()

var = Hero()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_SPACE:
                    var.Attack()
```

Comment: Do you want the circle to be drawn as long as you are holding the spacebar? Or do you want it to be drawn once you hit your spacebar, and then move to a new location when you hit the spacebar again? Or do you want it to be drawn constantly and follow your mouse as it moves?

Comment: I want it to draw whenever i draw my spacebar and then move when it hit it again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things you need to change to make it work. I've included a somewhat lengthy explanation behind all of these changes, so that you will be able to understand them and apply them correctly in other parts of your game. If you do not need the extra explanation, you can skip to working code at the bottom of this answer. I've placed comments everywhere I made a change.

### Event handling

Pygame keeps a list of events that happen in the game, such as keypresses. When you call `pygame.event.get()`, a list of all events that have happened *since the last call* is returned. This means that in your `Attack()` function, none of your code is being run because it happens for each event in `pygame.event.get()`, but `pygame.event.get()` returns an empty list because you just called it in the while loop. Generally speaking, you should only call `pygame.event.get()` once per loop, exactly like you have it in the bottom of your code. You should delete the for loop in `Attack()` because it has no purpose there.

### Quitting

A small inconvenience with pygame is that the close button doesn't work by default, which means you have to forcefully close your game. To fix this, you should check for QUIT events in your event loop, and close the game. Here's an example of how the code would look inserted into your game:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_SPACE:
                    var.Attack()
```

### Colors

Sadly, Pygame has no built-in Colors, so `BLUE` in `pygame.draw.circle(surface, BLUE, amntTuple, 20, 300)` will not work. Instead, replace `BLUE` with `pygame.Color(0,0,255)` to create blue yourself, using the RGB color model.

### Drawing

Drawing is done in two steps in Pygame. First, objects are drawn to a virtual surface, which can not be seen. Then, when you call `pygame.display.update()`, the virtual surface is drawn to the screen, which the user can see. This has technical advantages such as allowing the computer to draw smoothly without screen flickering, but it also means that as long as you don't call `pygame.display.update()`, nothing you draw will ever be seen.`pygame.display.update()`, nothing you draw will ever be visible. However, if you call it too many times, your game may flicker or act in unexpected ways. Because of this, you will generally want to call `pygame.display.update()` exactly once per gameloop (just like with `pygame.event.get()`). Generally, `pygame.display.update()` can be the very last line of code in your while loop, with everything else coming before it.

There are different ways you can do to draw to the screen in Pygame. One way is to use built-in functions like `pygame.draw.circle.` You were close in your use of it, but made two mistakes. First, BLUE doesn't exist, as I mentioned before. Second, the width parameter is the width of the line used to draw the circle, not the width of the circle itself. So you generally want it to be a small number. If you set the width to 0, the circle will be filled instead of drawn as an outline. Here's a fixed version of your draw.circle: `pygame.draw.circle(surface, pygame.Color(0,0,255), amntTuple, 20, 2)`

Another way to draw to the screen is with blitting. Everything in Pygame must be drawn to a Surface, which is like a virtual canvas. When you load an image using pygame.image.load(), the image is loaded as a Surface. And once you have a surface, you use blitting to draw it to the screen. For example:

```
man = pygame.image.load("/images/man.png")
surface.blit (man, (0,0))
```

would be used to draw an image of a man to the screen at pixels 0,0. This will be useful later in your game development process. However, the blit you currently have right after drawing your circle does nothing and causes errors because `self.space` and `self.spaceRect` do not exist, so you should delete it for now.

### The Working Code

```
import math
import pygame, sys, time 
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
WINDOW_WIDTH = 1000
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption('follow mouse')
surface.fill((255,255,255))

class Hero():
    def Attack(self):
        surface.fill ((255,255,255))
        amntTuple = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        #Use pygame.Color to make a color.
        #The last parameter is linewidth, and can be set to 0 for filled circles.
        pygame.draw.circle(surface, pygame.Color(0,0,255), amntTuple, 20, 2)
        #The blit was deleted because it did nothing and the broke code.

var = Hero()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            #Add a quit event so you can close your game normally.
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_SPACE:
                    var.Attack()

    #Update once at the end of each gameloop.
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following line (the last one in your program):

```
var.Attack
```

You aren't calling the `attack` function.

Replace it with

```
var.Attack()
```

and see if that works instead.

Answer (score 0):

The code is conceptually wrong, you should process events and update display only in the main loop:

```
...
class Hero():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attacks = []

    def attack(self):
        self.attacks.add(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

    def update(self):
        for amntTuple in self.attacks:
            pygame.draw.circle(surface, BLUE, amntTuple, 20, 300)
            surface.blit(self.space, self.spaceRect)

hero = Hero()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                hero.attack()

    # Clean background
    surface.fill((255,255,255))

    # Update/Draw sprites
    hero.update()

    # Update screen
    pygame.display.update()
```

During events you should only execute game logic to update status, then every frame you draw the screen according to the current status.