# Issues with surface.fill () in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

My program allows the an image to follow my mouse cursor but I am unable to draw the circle with the the `Attack` method because i have to `suface.fill` in the move method ( the move method is `followMeLittleBoy`) I can get the circle to draw for a split second but only while moving and it just barley. This is my full code other than my imports and such

```
class Hero ():

    def __init__(self):
        self.dead = False
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
        self.X_MOVE_AMT = 5
        self.Y_MOVE_AMT = 5
        self.space = pygame.image.load ("hero_sprite.jpg")
        self.spaceRect = self.space.get_rect()
        self.spaceRect.topleft = (100,100)
        surface.blit (self.space, self.spaceRect)
        pygame.display.update()

    def followMeLittleBoy (self):
        amntTuple = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.X_MOVE_AMT = math.ceil((amntTuple[0] - self.spaceRect.left)*0.2)
        self.Y_MOVE_AMT = math.ceil((amntTuple[1] - self.spaceRect.top)*0.2)
        self.spaceRect.left += self.X_MOVE_AMT
        self.spaceRect.top += self.Y_MOVE_AMT
        surface.blit (self.space, self.spaceRect)
        pygame.display.update()


    def Attack (self):
        surface.fill ((255,255,255))
        amntTuple = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        pygame.draw.circle(surface, pygame.Color(0,0,255), amntTuple, 20, 2)
        surface.blit (self.space, self.spaceRect)





var = Hero ()

while True:
    surface.fill((255,255,255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        var.followMeLittleBoy ()
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                var.Attack()
```

Answer (score 1):

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16970475/488012) I recommended you to update the state during events and call the draw routines from the main loop only once per iteration, this is specially important for the `surface.fill` call.

Now I strongly recommend to follow that aproach, otherwise this kind of problems will continue to arise.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that you need to fix.

1. `var.followMeLittleBoy()` should be called once per loop, not for every event.
2. You should have a seperate method for drawing in your Hero class.
3. Call pygame.display.update() only once per loop.

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you could create a list of circles that are to be drawn, and when you press spacebar, a circle is added to a list.

Then you can loop your circle list,and draw each of them without them dissapearing.